# CSP report-only doesn't report passive mixed content?

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I am using the below policy. It is not reporting passive mixed content like images loaded using http by a page in iframe.

```
default-src https:; report-uri <https reporting endpoint>;
```

Apparently, block-all-mixed-content directive also doesn't work: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/26

Tried a more detailed policy like in https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet#Mixed_Content_Policy with `img-src https: data:` as well. But that doesn't work too.

Is it that CSP reporting doesn't work for passive mixed content?

Comment: It didn't work for me, either. I've read lots of descriptions and am more confused than ever.

Comment: Firefox 56.0.2 (32).

Answer (score 0):

CSP does not "trickle down" to pages loaded in an iframe, it applies only to the resource it was delivered with. If you want to declare a CSP for the page in the iframe, you'll have to include a CSP header for that page too.

Comment: I have no Iframes on my site, but it is https containing an http image and I can't get an error out of csp. So confused. Firefox 56.0.2 (32).